# Android transition doesn't work

Tags: android, transition

I have two scenes:

Scene1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/AppTheme.TopPanel"
        android:id="@+id/top_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/AppTheme.Panel"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp">
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Scene2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/AppTheme.TopPanel"
        android:id="@+id/top_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/AppTheme.Panel"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And also I have an activity which contains the only fragment. When program begins I replace this fragment with my FirstFragment class. Inside of it I have a button. When you click it this code is executed:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ChangeBounds transitions = new ChangeBounds();
    transition.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
        //Other overrides...
        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
            SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
        //Other overrides...
    });
    ViewGroup sceneRoot = (ViewGroup) getView();
    Scene from = Scene.getSceneForLayout(sceneRoot, R.layout.scene1, getActivity());
    Scene to = Scene.getSceneForLayout(sceneRoot, R.layout.scene2, getActivity());
    from.enter();
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(sceneRoot, transitions);
    to.enter();
}
```

But transition not happen. It starts and next moment ends. Here's in action:

[image]

Where is my mistake?

Comment: debug and check whether the value of `transitions`  in TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(getView(), transitions); this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before implementing the transition between the first and second scene it is first necessary to add some code to load the layout from the `layout` file into a Scene instance. Remaining in the `SceneTransitionsActivity.java` file.

---

can try this way:

```
package com.example.scenetransitions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.transition.Scene;
import android.transition.Transition;
import android.transition.TransitionManager;
import android.transition.TransitionInflater;
import android.transition.TransitionManager;

public class SceneTransitionsActivity extends Activity {

ViewGroup rootContainer;
Scene scene1;
Scene scene2;
Transition transitionMgr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scene_transitions);

    rootContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.rootContainer);

    transitionMgr = TransitionInflater.from(this)
            .inflateTransition(R.transition.transition);

    scene1 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(rootContainer,R.layout.scene1_layout, this);

    scene2 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(rootContainer,R.layout.scene2_layout, this);

    scene1.enter();
}

public void goToScene2 (View view)
{
    TransitionManager.go(scene2, transitionMgr);
}

public void goToScene1 (View view)
{
    TransitionManager.go(scene1, transitionMgr);
}
.
.
.
}
```

refer: [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_Android_Scene_Transitions_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial) & [this](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/18e10d81e37be27229e47de9cd7870b4cd62b6c6/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Transitions.java).

Comment: I can't enter scene in onCreate. I have one layout as main which I use in onCreate, and two layouts to animate fragment changes. As I anderstand transition framework I should enter first scene then call beginDelayedTransition and then enter second one. But it doesn't work.